# How to declare anonymous class having data member dictionary type?

Tags: c#

I am having class

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public Dictionary<string, object> attr;
    public string state = "closed";
}
```

and I want to add the data in to the List

```
List<Person> mPer = new List<Person>();

mPer.Add(new Person() { data = "My tasks" },attr = new Dictionary<string, object>() {id= "1",title = "sdfsdf",description = "asdasdasd",rel = "Folder",parentID = DBNull.Value});
```

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: You are not using `Person` class in your code

Comment: yes "dose not contain definition for title" i am not even able to declare dictionary key and value.

Answer (score 3):

You should seperate your `key` and `value` for example:

```
  attr = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { key, { value } };
```

In your case:

```
 attr = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "myKey", new { id = 2, ... } };
```

If you want to add more than one item:

```
attr = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
        { "myKey", new {id = 2, title = "sdfsdf", description = "asdasdasd"} }, 
        { "myOtherKey", new {id = 3, title = "sdfsdsdf", description = "asdaasdasd" } }
        };
```

Notice that *curly braces*

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) for your dictionary property:

```
  attr = new Dictionary<string, object> {
            { "id",  "1" },
            { "title", "sdfsdf" },
            { "description", "asdasdasd" },
            { "rel",  "Folder" },
            { "parentID", DBNull.Value }
         }
```

Whole collection initializer for the dictionary is enclosed in braces. Inner braces enclose the initializer for key/value pair that will be added to `Dictionary<string, object>`.

I suggest you to read MSDN article [How to: Initialize a Dictionary with a Collection Initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx)

---

Complete code should look like:

```
mPer.Add(new Person { 
           Name = "My tasks", // no braces here
           attr = new Dictionary<string, object> {
                { "id",  "1" },
                { "title", "sdfsdf" },
                { "description", "asdasdasd" },
                { "rel",  "Folder" },
                { "parentID", DBNull.Value }
           }
         });
```